# Testing a static method from a singleton in Jest (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

```
// tester.js
class Tester {
  static loggit(text) {
    return text;
  }
}

module.exports = new Tester();
```

When testing this singleton in Node.js using Jest

```
// tester.spec.js
const Tester = require('./tester.js');

describe('Tester testing', () => {
  it('logs it', () => {
    expect(Tester.loggit('test')).toEqual('test');
  });
});
```

When running the test, I get an error saying "encountered a declaration exception. TypeError: Tester.loggit is not a function"

I tried using `jest.requireActual` to resolve it, but it's not fixing the error.

I don't want to export the class itself as it will be a singleton in my app.

Any input will be helpful.

Comment: Static method in a singleton? Why?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to export the class itself, not an instance of the class:

```
module.exports = Tester;
```

And if just have `static` methods, you could just export an object:

```
 module.exports = {
  loggit(it) { return it; },
 };
```

If you really want to have both a singleton and static properties (what purpose should that serve?!), then you can get the class from an instance using the constructor property:

```
 (new Tester).constructor.loggit("test")
```